# Don't allow Japanese characters in a TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, textbox

What would be the best way to make sure a user does not enter (or copies) Japanese characters into a C# WinForms TextBox?

The problem is that our software will be used by German, English and Japanese users. All kinds of characters and symbols are handled well, but Japanese characters seem to cause some trouble in the underlying persistence framework.

Comment: You're probably better off fixing the backend.  Your Japanese users will be p.o.-ed if they can't use their native language with the software they've purchased from you.

Comment: then you should fix the underlying persistence solution. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Of course the backend will be fixed ASAP. Nevertheless I need a working solution right away with as few side effects as possible...

Comment: @Matt Laughing out loud...by myself...in my office.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a whitelist? For example:

```
bool IsValidInput(String input)
{
    return input != null && input.All(c => IsValidLetter(c));
}

bool IsValidLetter(char c)
{
     return Char.IsNumber(c) || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}
```

Although i must agree that the best approach would be to fix your problems with japanese characters if you want japanese customers.

Answer (score 1):

Please read my comment.  I really suggest you fix the persistent piece to work correctly.  But since that does not answer your question you've got two options:

1. Use a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) with a mask and a few options.  Or write your own `MaskedTextProvider`.
2. Alternatively: handle the validation event, and manually check each character to ensure it's not in the Japanese range of unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

While I concur with the previous posters, and thus don't want to do a *me too* answer, I'd like to add something regarding specifically input of "Latin" text by Japanese people. In 99.99999% (yeah that's five 9s, we're talking Erlang-like reliability here ;-) of the cases, even when they enter a text in Latin characters, say **SUZUKI** (a common family name), what you are *really* going to get is **ＳＵＺＵＫＩ**. Codepoints in the `FF20-FF60` range. Oops, I broke your persistence engine again. And pissed off the customers. Because they won't understand why you are rejecting their perfectly correct **Latin** characters. Or so they thought...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for only english characters;

```
private void txtSmsMessage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //sadece latin karakterlerin girilmesi saglanıyor.
            string str = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
            byte[] key = null;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            {
                key = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str.Substring(str.Length - 1, 1));
                if (Convert.ToInt32(key[1]) != 0 || (Convert.ToInt32(key[0]) < 32 && Convert.ToInt32(key[0]) > 127))
                {
                    txtSmsMessage.Text = txtSmsMessage.Text.Substring(0, str.Length - 1);
                    txtSmsMessage.SelectionStart = txtSmsMessage.Text.Length;
                    return;
                }
            }
}
```

if you want to work another language, please check this link.
http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html